# Does Magento supports attribute with type date, not datetime

Tags: magento

I have problem with this format and I don't know does magento support it.
In code I have:

```
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'release_date', array(
   'input'         => 'date',
   'type'          => 'datetime',
   'label'         => 'Release date',
   'backend'       => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime',
   'visible'       => true,
   'required'      => false,
   'user_defined'  => true,
   'visible_on_front' => true,
   'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL
 ));
```

How to change type to date? And how to make it dependable from Magento locale?

Comment: I find out that Magento doesn't have date type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here solution....

```
  $data = array(
       "attribute_code" => "date_attribute_3",
       "frontend_input" => "date",
       "default_value" => "06/19/2014",
       "is_unique" => 0,
       "is_global"=>"1",
       "is_required" => 0,
       "apply_to" => array("simple"),
       "is_configurable" => 0,
       "is_searchable" => 0,
       "is_visible_in_advanced_search" => 0,
       "is_comparable" => 0,
       //"is_global" =>1,
       "is_used_for_promo_rules" => 0,
       "is_visible_on_front" => 0,
       "used_in_product_listing" => 0,
       "additional_fields" => array(),
       "frontend_label" => array(array("store_id" => "0", "label" => "my date"))
      );

    $Attribute=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->create($data);
```